# forward-word and non-letter "words"

Tags: navigation, syntax-table, syntax, characters, words

Using `forward-word` with this line:

```
foo *** *** bar,
```

I want to have the folowing behavior:

```
foo| ***| ***| bar|,
```

Not:

```
foo| *** *** bar|,
```

So, if between spaces there are only non-letter symbols, let's consider this a word too. `forward-whitespace` is not good enough, cause it loses distinction between letters and non-letters at all.
How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `forward-sexp` instead (bound to `C-M-f`).  Likewise, `backward-sexp` (`C-M-b`).

See (elisp) [List Motion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Motion.html).

---

If you don't want to do that then you'll need to change the syntax  for character `*` in your buffer to be word syntax:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?* "w")
```

Or for a given syntax table, `my-table`:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?* "w" my-table)
```